# How do I correctly filter intermittent "NoneType" values in row-wise apply functions?

Tags: python, pandas

Disclaimer: I can't copy/paste from a work terminal, so the below is a reproduction of the issue with a different code and no data.

I'm struggling to understand how to "handle" inline bad-data with apply functions without bailing out on type errors. Some example code below demonstrates the issue.

I've tried cleaning the data earlier, without much luck. I've stopped trying after using the `convert-to-scalar` trick below.

```
def afunc(x):
  #will error out on "NoneType"
  if (x.value.isnull() or x.value2.isnull()): return "blah"
  ## will work
  a = x.value
  b = x.value2
  if (a and b): return "blah"
  return "not blah"

aDf.apply(afunc,axis=1)
```

Could someone provide some insight as to what's going on? Should I be catching exceptions and working that way?

Comment: np.where(x.value.isnull()|x.value2.isnull(),'blah','')

Comment: I would do type checking at the beginning of the function: `if x.value is None`

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I've added a few defensive checks earlier in the function, I was still getting the answer. I did not try the numpy idea - I will make sure I can still reproduce the issue tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will work in your case:

```
def afunc(x):
  if (x.value == None or x.value2 == None): return "blah"
  ## will work
  a = x.value
  b = x.value2
  if (a and b): return "blah"
  return "not blah"

aDf['result'] = aDf.apply(afunc,axis=1)
```